# how to call javascript function when I click on a node in jquery tree

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2-jquery

I would like to ask some help.

I write the code as the following when I click a node to call the java action method :

```
<sjt:tree id="treeDynamicAjax"
    jstreetheme="apple" 
    rootNode="#session.UNT_LIST"
    childCollectionProperty="children"
    nodeTitleProperty="title" 
    nodeIdProperty="id"
    openAllOnLoad="true"
    nodeHref="popUntSel!selectUnit.action"
    nodeHrefParamName="g_selected_uid"
    ></sjt:tree>
```

It is ok to call action method. But I have no idea to call javascript function when I click a node and how can I know the unit id value in javascript???

Here is the ref link for struts2 jquery tree : http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Set a topic for the tree's `onClickTopics` attribute, subscribe to that topic, and implement your click handler.

Comment: After i put code onClickTopics="treeClicked" in <sjt:tree> tag, but it doesn't work. I tried to put alert in script, but i have no luck. here is script coding : <script>
$(function(){
$(".jstree ul li").live('click',function(){ <br>alert("click on tree node"); });
$. Subscribe ('treeClicked', function (event, data){
var item = event.originalEvent.data.rslt.obj;
alert ('Clicked ID : ' + item.attr ("id"));
});
});
</script>

Comment: Now, I can call the script method when the tree node is clicked. :)
Thanks, @DaveNewton